# How to find a match in multiple 2d list?

Tags: python, dataframe, multidimensional-array, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I have two 2d list with large amount of rows and different size length for both lists. I'm having trouble with finding match in each sub-list in df1 and df2. Let say I would like to find a match from df1 in df2 I would like to return the matching values and non-matching values. which will probably convert into a 3d list then I would like to remove the bracket and convert it back to 2d list. If there's a way to convert into 2d list without converting into 3d list first would help me out a lot.

Here a short example (My 2d list)

```
 df1 = [[1, 7, 3, 5], [2, 5, 14, 10]]
 df2 = [[1, 17, 3, 5], [34, 14, 74], [34, 3, 87], [25, 14, 10]]
```

Convert to 3d list.

```
 match = [[[1,3,5], [],[3], []], [[5],[14], [], [10,14]]]
 no_match = [[[17], [], [34,87], []], [[1,3,17], [34,74], [], [25]]]
```

Desire Result (Remove Brackets and convert back to 2d list).

```
 match = [[1,3,5], [3], [5], [14], [14,10]]
 no_match = [[17], [34,87], [1,3,17], [34,74], [25]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use nested loops to iterate in dicts:

```
matches = []
no_matches = []

for sublist1 in df1:
    for sublist2 in df2:
        match = [val for val in sublist1 if val in sublist2]
        no_match = [val for val in sublist2 if val not in sublist1]
        
        if match: matches.append(match)
        if no_match: no_matches.append(no_match)

print("matches:", matches)
print("no matches:", no_matches)
```

Comment: The matches are correct, but the no matches don't work as desire. For example [ 34,14,74] & [25,14,10] & [34,3,87] doesn't match. Is there a way to fix this.

Comment: what about this approach ?
`matches = []
no_matches = []

for sublist1 in df1:
    for sublist2 in df2:
        match = [val for val in sublist1 if val in sublist2]
        no_match_1 = [val for val in sublist1 if val not in sublist2]
        no_match_2 = [val for val in sublist2 if val not in sublist1]
        
        if match: matches.append(match)
        if no_match_1 or no_match_2: no_matches.append(no_match_1 + no_match_2)

print("matches:", matches)
print("no matches:", no_matches)`